# Touch change modified time including seconds

Tags: linux

I am getting `invalid date format 2011` when I try to the modified time, this works fine without the seconds

```
touch -t 2011 08 23 14 05 14 voucher.tpl
```

I am a little confused with the below that explains how to do this:

**-t time** 
specifies a particular time using this format:

```
[[[[cc]yy]MM]dd]hhmm[.ss]
```

where cc is the optional first 2 digits of the year, yy is the optional last 2 digits of the year, MM is the optional number of the month (01-12), dd is the optional day of the month, hh is the hour in 24 hour format (required), mm is the minutes (required), ss is the optional seconds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ touch -t 201108231405.14 voucher.tpl
$ ls -l --time-style='+%B %d %H:%M:%S' voucher.tpl
-rw-r--r-- 1 quanta quanta 0 August 23 14:05:14 voucher.tpl
```

Comment: $ /bin/touch -m -t 201903100248.11 2019-03-10-02-48-03.nef <br>
/bin/touch: invalid date format ‘201903100248.11’ <br> apparently there is hidden magic, too?

Answer (score 4):

Remove spaces. Also, you're missing the period between the mm and the ss. This will work:

```
touch -t 201108231405.14 voucher.pl
```

Answer (score 2):

`touch -t 201108231405.14 voucher.tpl` should work. It did for me.

Note that the time format specification does not include any spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong format.

This should work fine:

```
touch -t 201108231405.14 voucher.tpl
```

> -t STAMP
>
> use `[[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss]` instead of current time